# FullCalendar agregar festivos automaticamente.

Tags: php, html, laravel, symfony, fullcalendar

Hay alguna manera de agregar a fullcalendar, en este caso utilizo el framework de laravel, los festivos nacionales de forma "automatica"? Se que puedo crear arrays, y se como agregarlos digamos haciendo un insert desde un botón, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de añadirlos todos o los nacionales al menos sin necesidad de agregarlos a mano.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Los dias festivos son publicados cada año en el BOE segun la CA (comunidad autonoma) y la localidad. Ya que hay festivos nacionales, regionales y locales, y en algunos casos esos festivos no caen el mismo dia. Ejemplo, lunes de pasqua, cae siempre en lunes, pero pocas veces en el mismo dia del mes, segun el año.

Comment: y tendria alguna manera de hacer una consulta estilo como si fuera un webservice y cargar todos esos datos en mi bd de manera que luego lo implementes automáticamente? Rollo hacer como una actualización anual de los festivos que existen, no se si alguien ha pensado en algo parecido, me imagino que no se podrá, pero por preguntar que no quede.. Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

Comment: Hasta el día de hoy, no he visto un servicio ofial de estado, donde se puedan consultar esos datos mediante una API para los servicios informaticos. (si alguien los ha encontrado o han implementado tal servicio, tambien me interesa).

Comment: En mi caso particular, nos ha tocado realizar esa tarea manualmente ya que nuestros clientes son provinciales (por el momento).

Comment: Menuda suerte.. me cayeron a mi todos jeje. Investigare un poco en estos aspectos y si me entero de algo, lo publicaré, muchas gracias por tus aportaciones. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

tenía la misma duda. Puedes agregarlos desde el calendario de Google.

```
eventSources:'{{ url('events/show') }}',// Carga otro calendario

                    googleCalendarApiKey: 'API DE CALENDARIO',
                    events: {
                        googleCalendarId: '12345678#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
                        textColor: 'orange' // an option!




                       
                        
                    }
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar